# modify user-defined System Variables(that is a number) of remote Server machine using ssh?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, arithmetic

I want to modify the value of a System Variable of a remote server .

The IP of server is 172.16.22.53.

The server runs Windows OS,and Cygwin instlled in it.In /cygdrive/c/cygwind/home/sikaiwei/.bashrc file(in Windows),I created a new System Variables and definded it.And I want the Variable to be a number,so I can change its value freely using ssh in my bash script .
I try it ,but the system variable seem be a string instead of a number.

```
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 ~]$ $ORANGE
-bash: 1: command not found
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 ~]$ export ORANGE=1+$ORANGE
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 ~]$ $ORANGE
-bash: 1+1: command not found
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 ~]$
```

Like that,I defined a system variable $ORANGE to 1.Then 1 plus it to get 2，but I got '1+1' instead of '2'！

@skwllsp  @Thorsten Staerk ,thanks! Your ways work well both.
But if I ues sshpass like this :

```
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 v1.4]$ sshpass -p 'CHUN~19900405' ssh 172.16.22.53 -l sikaiwei     "getId=$ORANGE;echo $ORANGE;let ORANGE=$ORANGE+1;echo $ORANGE;echo 'getId is'$getId;"
1
1
getId is
```

But the result should like this:

```
1
2
getId is 1
```

What happened?

I try this：

```
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 v1.4]$ sshpass -p 'CHUN~19900405' ssh 172.16.22.53 -l sikaiwei "getId=$ORANGE;echo $ORANGE;ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1));echo $ORANGE;echo 'getId is '+$getId;"
1
1
getId is +
```

and

```
[sikaiwei@login-1-2 v1.4]$ sshpass -p 'CHUN~19900405' ssh 172.16.22.53 -l sikaiwei "getId=$ORANGE;echo $ORANGE;((ORANGE=ORANGE+1));echo $ORANGE;echo 'getId is '+$getId;"
1
1
getId is +
```

I find a big error. The value of $ORANGE in

```
sshpass -p 'CHUN~19900405' ssh 172.16.22.53 -l sikaiwei "getId=$ORANGE;echo $ORANGE;    ((ORANGE=ORANGE+1));echo $ORANGE;echo 'getId is '+$getId;"
```

is not the value of the System Variable of the Server host.

It is the value of the System Variable of my Client host.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html: `let ORANGE=$ORANGE+1`

Comment: Thanks! But if I change the variable and exit and log in again,the variable don't changed!? Can I permantly change the value of variable  regardless of rebooting the computer machine  just using bash command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arithmetic operator is $(()):

```
tstaerk@euve31070:~$ export orange=$((1+$orange))
tstaerk@euve31070:~$ echo $orange
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of a variable is a string. Even if it was a number, `1+$ORANGE` is not a number, and neither is `1+1`: both are strings which, when evaluated as arithmetic expressions, yield a number.

You can use the [arithmetic expression syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to tell the shell that you want to perform arithmetic.

```
ORANGE=$((1+ORANGE))
```

Bash has an alternate syntax to perform arithmetic operations:

```
((ORANGE=ORANGE+1))
((ORANGE+=1))
```

In bash, you can also [declare](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) a variable as integer-valued. If you do that, assignments to that variable perform arithmetic expansion on the value that you assign, and signal an error if the value isn't a well-formed arithmetic expression.

```
declare -i ORANGE
ORANGE=1
ORANGE=1+ORANGE
```

Comment: Thanks！But I try them I writed just now.Because I want to modify the value of a System Variable of a remote server .The server runs Windows OS,and Cygwin instlled in it.